# deleting previous entry of server

Tags: php

i have made a server using php. The server is getting new information after some time. I want the server page to display only the current information. when a new information is received, it should delete the previous one and show only the recent. Can you help me in this.
my current code is:

```
        <?php 
   $fp=fopen("random.txt","a");
   fwrite($fp,$_POST['data']."\n");
   echo $_POST['data'];
   fclose($fp);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `a` to `w` or `r+` to write new information each time:

```
$fp = fopen("random.txt", "r+");
```

The `a` means append which is why you were appending to previous file rather than writing new information.